# Potential problems with storing the second table of two dimensional arrays in the index

Tags: lua, lua-table

In the past I found myself using a table as index and value of
a table when the order was irrelevant.
Since every table returns a unique value they are save to use as
index and with that I already got all the information I want to
use later on in the program. Now I did not see any similar lua code
jet and didn't use it in a non test-program. So I'm worrying that I
might get some unforeseen/unexpected problems when using this method.

example:

```
a = {1,2,3,4,5}                         --some testing values
b = {2,nil,4,nil,1}
c = {3,nil,nil,nil,2}
d = {4,nil,1,nil,3}
e = {5,1,2,3,4}

tab = {a,b,c,d,e}
t = {}

for i, v in pairs(tab) do
    t[v] = 0
end

for iv in pairs(t) do                   --is almost every time outputting it in a different order
    print(iv[1],iv[2],iv[3],iv[4],iv[5])        --could be a list of data where you have to go through all of it anyway
end

io.read()
```

Now I can store some additional information in t[v] but if I don't have
any is there maybe some lua-type that is smaller?

Edit:

Does this go well with the use of weak-tables?

Note:

Standard 2d table: table[key1] = table

**table[key1][key2]** <-- contains stuff

this version: table[table] = anything but nil <-- not accessible over table[key1][key2]

**key1[key2]** <-- contains stuff

Comment: I don't understand your last sentence.

Comment: @lhf t[v] which I'm initializing as 0 is only needed because nil would mean the table does not exist. So using a value that uses an as small as possible amount of memory would save quite some if this is to get big.

Comment: 0 takes as little as possible; so does `false`.

Comment: @CHlM3RA: If you are concerned about memory: Using small positive integer keys (like with `tab`) will probably consume less memory than your method (`t`), because Lua implements an optimization for array-like tables where the keys are not stored explicitly.

Comment: @lhf and siffiejoe: thanks that answers the nice to know part of my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine to use a table as a key in another table.

However, note that different tables will be different keys, even of the tables have the same contents.

Comment: Under normal circumstances yes but week-tables may get confused I have to look at them the next days.
I think there was something with key and index.